# Iterate Grib2 values using GribCS library C#?

Tags: c#, grib

I'm using suggested library [GribCS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gribcs/) It has not any sample or example that shows iteration about Lat/Lon with their respective values to store in a readable forms. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you must use coordinates iteration as I'm doing below and also you have to set your require parameters condition to extract related values.

```
    static void ReadGribTwoFile()
    {
        #region Grib 2 Code
        Grib2Input input = new Grib2Input(RandomAccessFile);

        if (!input.scan(false, false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to successfully scan grib file");
            return;
        }
        Grib2Data data = new Grib2Data(RandomAccessFile);

        var records = input.Records;

        foreach (Grib2Record record in records)
        {
            IGrib2IndicatorSection iis = record.Is;
            IGrib2IdentificationSection id = record.ID;
            IGrib2ProductDefinitionSection pdsv = record.PDS;
            IGrib2GridDefinitionSection gdsv = record.GDS;

            long time = id.RefTime.AddTicks(record.PDS.ForecastTime * 3600000).Ticks;

            Console.WriteLine("Record description at " + " forecast " + new DateTime(time) + ": " + string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", iis.Discipline, pdsv.ParameterCategory, pdsv.ParameterNumber));

            float[] values = data.getData(record.getGdsOffset(), record.getPdsOffset());

            if ((iis.Discipline == 0) && (pdsv.ParameterCategory == 1) && (pdsv.ParameterNumber == 1))
            {
                // RH
                int c = 0;
                for (double lat = gdsv.La1; lat >= gdsv.La2; lat = lat - gdsv.Dy)
                {
                    for (double lon = gdsv.Lo1; lon <= gdsv.Lo2; lon = lon + gdsv.Dx)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("RH " + lat + "\t" + lon + "\t" + values[c]);
                        c++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```